# Nonlinear regression / Curve fitting with L-infinity norm

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting

I am looking into time series data compression at the moment.

The idea is to fit a curve on a time series of n points so that the maximum deviation of any of the points is not greater than a given threshold. In other words, none of the values that the curve takes at the points where the time series is defined should be "further away" than a certain threshold from the actual values.

Till now I have found out how to do nonlinear regression using the least squares estimation method in R (`nls` function) and other languages, but I haven't found any packages that implement nonlinear regression with the L-infinity norm.

I have found papers on ["Non-linear curve fitting in the $L_1$ and $L_{\infty}$ norms"](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2006101?uid=3737864&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21100693651721), by Shrager and Hill and ["A linear  programming algorithm  for curve fitting in the $L_{\infty}$ norm"](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a080454.pdf), by Armstrong and Sklar.

I could try to implement this in R for instance, but I first looking to see if this hasn't already been done and that I could maybe reuse it.

I have found a solution that I don't believe to be "very scientific": I use nonlinear least squares regression to find the starting values of the parameters which I subsequently use as starting points in the R `optim` function that minimizes the maximum deviation of the curve from the actual points.

The idea is to be able to find out if this type of curve-fitting is possible on a given time series sequence and to determine the parameters that allow it.

Comment: Function interpolation (in the form of Chebyshev or Bernstein polynomials) may be of interest to you. From Weierstrass’ Theorem, these approaches provide bounds on the L-infinity error of any function over a closed interval.

Comment: Could this be done not with polynomials, but with functions of the form a*sin(b*x), for instance?

Comment: I only mention the work on polynomial interpolation because I have some experience with it. I THINK the specific type of function you choose is not important as long as the basis functions are orthogonal. Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 3):

For those who may be interested, I have found a paper that proposes a solution to my problem: ["A min-max algorithm for non-linear regression models"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0096300383900322), by A. Tishler and I. Zang.

I have tested it myself, and I get the results I need.